# How to add scalar to Sympy Matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, sympy

While working with Numpy arrays, i had this code

```
Size = 2      #initializing size, arrays(Matrices)
k = 3
Aklinnonlin = array([[k, 1], [0, -0.5]])
xstartswitchpoint = array([[5.], [5.]])   #y,Vy

def dxdt_y(Aklinnonlin, xstartswitchpoint, b2x2):   
    dydx[0] = xstartswitchpoint[1]         ##y' = Vy
    dydx[1] = -1 * Aklinnonlin[0][0] * (xstartswitchpoint[1]) - 9.81         ##Vy' = -k*Vy-g
    return dydx

for i, number in enumerate(range(Size)):
     k1[i] = hn * dxdt(A, x, b)[i]             
for i, number in enumerate(range(Size)):
     k2[i] = hn * dxdt(A, x + k1[i], b)[i]         
for j in range(Size): 
    k2k1norm[j] = float(dxdt(A,x+k1[j],b)[j])-float(dxdt(A,x,b)[j] )
```

Now, with switching from Numpy to Sympy I have this

```
matrix_size = 2
Aklinnonlin = Matrix([[k, 1], [0, -0.5]])
xstartswitchpoint = Matrix([[5.], [5.]])
dydx = zeros(matrix_size, 1)

def dxdt_y(dydx,Aklinnonlin, xstartswitchpoint, b2x2): 
    dydx[0, 0] = sum([dydx[0, 0], xstartswitchpoint[1, 0]])  
    dydx[1, 0] = -1 * Aklinnonlin[0, 0] * (xstartswitchpoint[1, 0]) - 9.81  ##Vy' = -k*Vy-g
k1= zeros(matrix_size,1)
k2 = zeros(matrix_size,1)
k2k1norm = zeros(matrix_size,1)


          
            for i in (range(matrix_size)):
                k1[i, 0] = hn * dxdt(dydx,A, x, b)[i,0]  
            #print(k1,'k1')

            for i in (range(matrix_size)):
                newxfork2[i, 0] = Matrix([x[i, 0]]) + Matrix([k1[i, 0]]) 
    #wrong result, because not the same operation
                # k2[i][0] = hn * dxdt(A, x+k1[i], b)[i]
                # k2[i] = hn * dxdt(A, x + k1[i], b)[i] 
                #k2[i, 0] = hn * dxdt(dydx,A, Matrix([x[i,0]]) + Matrix([k1[i,0]]), b)[i,0]
    #wrong result, because not the same operation
            k2[i, 0] = hn * dxdt(dydx, A,newxfork2, b)[i, 0]

for j in range(matrix_size):  
    k2k1norm[j, 0] = float(dxdt(dydx, A, newxfork2, b)[j, 0]) - float(dxdt(dydx, A, x, b)[j, 0])
#wrong result, because not the same operation
```

Usually, Sympy has Matrix+Matrix operation, but you can't add (1,1) to (2,1),
So x+Matrix([k1[i,0]]) wouldn't work.

Comment: Simplify the example.  I can't tell, by just reading, where the problem is.  Or even where you are try to "add a scalar to a Matrix".  And why `sympy`?  I don't see any defined `symbols`.  For numeric work, it's matrix functionality is quite limited compared to `numpy`.

Comment: When I worked with numpy, I had (array)+(element of array), and it worked. But in Sympy you can't do this. You can have different Matrix operations, such as adding Matrix to Matrix, multiplication, transpose, inverse. But not adding a scalar.

Comment: You can do `M + scalar*ones(*M.shape)`

Comment: `numpy` when allowing addition of a scalar is making use of its `broadcasting` mechanism.  That allows it to do operations between arrays with different numbers of dimensions (think of a scalar as a 0d array).  If `Matrix` does not document a similar `broadcasting` it doesn't provide the same kind of flexibility.

Comment: Thanks, @OscarBenjamin. This works. But somewhere problem, that result is not the same as Numpy. But, really, thanks.